# GET request to a web service returns HTTP 0 error

Tags: web-services, rest, get

I'm testing [this](http://ebsexprst%E2%80%902.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/employees) web service with [resttesttest](https://resttesttest.com) and getting the same error all the time:

> Oh no! Javascript returned an HTTP 0 error. One common reason this
>   might happen is that you requested a cross-domain resource from a
>   server that did not include the appropriate CORS headers in the
>   response. Better open up your Firebug...

Is this something with the URL or it's just my ignorance?

How to get JSON data from there?

**Update. Solution found.**

There was 2 reasons why my request didn't work:

1) I've copied the url from a pdf file and because of that it had some problems with encoding, which resulted in requesting the url in [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

2) For some reason [resttesttest](https://resttesttest.com) didn't want to work even with correct url so I've checked once again in Chrome's [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set what headers to allow, in order to get a Cross-origin resource sharing ([wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). If you use Node.JS, check something like this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-  Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
```

Or use your language syntax to set response headers.